# creative sb audigy se doesnt play sound

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card, creative

the pc of my girlfriend doesn't play sound, she changed the sound card from Realtek to Creative sb audigy se and everything seems okey, when you go to windows sound properties. on playback devices when you play something it shows those bars moving and on "teamviewer" pc sounds i can hear her pc, but unfortunately she doesnt hear sounds...and we simply...dont know what to do. Her OS is Win7 I will add any useful and necessary info. just for now don't know what could help...
It was working but now suddenly is not working at all. All things related to realtek are uninstalled and audigy is made the default.

Comment: Are drivers installed?

Comment: yes they are installed.

Comment: Did you install drivers from CD or website?  CD is horribly out of date and should not be used.  Goto creative.com and get the newest version if you don't already have that version.

Comment: Is she using stereo speakers? If so, are they plugged into the green 3.5 mm (headphone size) jack?

Comment: Drivers are from creative site and she uses headphones, plugged in green jack.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using headphones then I don't think that the headphones are plugged into the green jack. Green jack is for the speakers not for headphones. For headphones there should be pink coloured jacks check in front or back of computer to see if you have got them(every system have headphone jacks). Also try some speakers that allow to plug headphones in them to see if they(headphones) work.

Comment: Isn't green for sound output, pink for input (mic) ?
Headphones has two plugs one green one pink.

Comment: So does your mic work perfect? Can you also confirm if your speaker works at her place? Check if set of speakers are working fine or not.